# Annotation @RolesAllowed does not work on Web Service deployed in Tomcat 7.0.32

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, jax-ws, tomcat7

I think I am really stuck on this for 4 hours now.
I have a sample web service developed in JAX-WS, I have successfully configured BASIC authentication in web.xml but I just cannot make the annoation "@RolesAllowed" to work. This annotation is simply ignored.
I am using servlet 3.0 API and tomcat 7.0.32 so I believe @RolesAllowed should be supported.

The following is my code:
In Web.xml I have the following configuration:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ApexeWebServiceCollection</web-resource-name>
        <description>These resources are only accessible by authorised client.</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>These are the roles who have access.</description>
        <role-name>developer</role-name>
        <role-name>tester</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>This is how the user data must be transmitted.</description>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>default</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Service developer</description>
    <role-name>developer</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>Service tester</description>
    <role-name>tester</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Then I implemented the following method on the service side. I want method: "sayNumber" can only be accessed by "developer", not "tester":

@SchemaValidation(handler = SchemaValidationErrorHandler.class)
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.webservice.HelloWorld")

public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

@Override
@WebMethod
@RolesAllowed("developer")
public int sayNumber(double number) throws SOAPException {
    MessageContext messageContext = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    boolean isAllowed=wsContext.isUserInRole("developer");
    System.out.println("Authorization:"+isAllowed);
    return (int) ++number;
}
```

}

Then in the Spring configuration (Yes I also use Spring 3.1.2) I have the following to hook up the URI and the service:

```
<wss:binding url="/hello">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#helloWorldWebService"
            bindingID="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/" />
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

Next, I use a client to call this web service. The client is using a user name and password in "tester" role. I can see the service is printing "Authorization:false" because the code in HelloWorldImpl:

```
boolean isAllowed=wsContext.isUserInRole("developer");
    System.out.println("Authorization:"+isAllowed);
```

Certainly I can throw an exception here to kick the tester out. However, I want annotation "@RolesAllowed" to do the work. I have tried many ways but this annotation simply does not work (Annotation is ignored). 
Please help.

Comment: Nobody knows about that?